# Why does df.merge() reduce the size of the dataframe like this?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge 3 data frames along a common column "Country", but when I do the length of the df gets cut down to 6. Here are quick snapshots of the three original data frames.
[image: energy][[image: GDPScimEn]
[image: ScimEn]

Their lengths are 227, 264, and 15 respectively. However when I merge them I get this with a length of only 6 entries ( am checking using len(df))
[image: df]
I am using

```
df = ScimEn.merge(energy).merge(GDP)
```

`df.set_index('Country', inplace=True)`

Comment: Please, do not post images, it's easier for everyone if you copy and paste the outputs of the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the default join of `.merge()` is an inner join as described in the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Your merge then only returns the set of rows where `Country` is found in all three dataframes. You should instead try to specify which type of join you want, with the keyword `how: {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’}, default ‘inner’`. For example an outer join:

```
df = ScimEn.merge(energy, how='Outer').merge(GDP, how='Outer')
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you.